# hide the boostrap 4 fixed navbar during ajax call

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-4

Just wondering how one would go about hiding a boostrap 4 fixed-top navbar during a ajax call loading data from the database.  Then after the ajax call the navbar would be shown again.

Would this work?

```
$('{navbarSelector}').hide();
 $.ajax(
     url: "fetchData.php",
     success: function(result){
         $('{navbarSelector}').show();
}});
```

replacing the {navbarSelector} text with the correct selector.  I've tried 
using the 'navbar' class as the {navbarSelector} but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance for any assistants.

Comment: It will be really nice if you create jsfiddle version.

Comment: Could it be have important display css property?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that the navbar provides hide() and show() functionality?

You could try the following:

```
$('{navbarSelector}').css("display","none");
$.ajax(
   url: "fetchData.php",
   success: function(result){
     $('{navbarSelector}').css("display","block");
}});
```

It would be nice if you had some more information.